# "Edit and Continue" doesn't work - VS2010 with TFS - Locked files in the Solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, edit-and-continue, locked-files

In my Visual Studio 2010 the Edit & Continue debug functionality with a specific Solution under TFS doesn't work. There's no error, but when the execution of the application stops at the breakpoint, I can't modify the files with the code. It seems that TFS has locked the files for my user.

I have tried:

1) To ensure Read/Write permissions to the files

2) To verify that all projects was built **strictly** for x86 (I have Win7 64 bit)

3) To disable the check JIT in Options/Debug

4) I also tried to restore to the initial conditions the VS 2010 settings with Tools/Import-Export Settings

5) I have tried to import the settings from a pc of a my collaborator, in which Edit & Continue works well

With other solutions, not stored in TFS, I have no problem.
How can I allow Edit & Continue for this solution?

Comment: Are you building your application for AnyCPU on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: @Steve: no I'm building for x86 and, yes, I have Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: I hope that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041913/find-all-locked-files-in-tfs) could help you to pinpoint the problem. Buonanotte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue was a Visual Studio addin to work with SQL Compact. I have seen that there isn't issues if I sart Visual Studio in safe mode.